# libgit2 (git_status_byindex(status, i))->head_to_index->old_file.path is NULL, why? (libgit status example)

Tags: c, libgit2

how can i get status in libgits2's examples to work? as i keep getting NULL for s->head_to_index->old_file.path and the docs https://libgit2.org/docs/guides/101-samples/#status and the  api site https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/status/git_status_byindex are of little help

and the original examples src/status.c crashes on git cloned repositories

```
Enter command line arguments.
> status --git-dir=../libgit2
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
SIGSEGV on thread : 1083740160
```

Yet if i copy the file to the repo and compile it it works but still is null

```
Enter command line arguments.
> status2 
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   (null)
#   new file:   (null)
#   new file:   (null)
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   (null)
#   (null)
#   (null)
#   (null)
```

however if i use a foreach instead

```
void gitprefix(parse_optsST)(struct opts *o, int argc, char *argv[]);
void gitprefix(show_branchST)(git_repository *repo, int format);
int gitprefix(ensure_there_are_changes_to_stash)(git_repository * repo);
void gitprefix(print_shortST)(git_repository *repo, git_status_list *status);
int gitprefix(print_submodST)(git_submodule *sm, const char *name, void *payload);

int gitprefix(status)(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    git_repository *repo = NULL;
    git_status_list *status;
    struct gitprefix(optsST) o = { GIT_STATUS_OPTIONS_INIT, ".",0,0,0,0,0,0 };

    git_libgit2_init();

    o.statusopt.show  = GIT_STATUS_SHOW_INDEX_AND_WORKDIR;
    o.statusopt.flags = GIT_STATUS_OPT_INCLUDE_UNTRACKED |
        GIT_STATUS_OPT_RENAMES_HEAD_TO_INDEX |
        GIT_STATUS_OPT_SORT_CASE_SENSITIVELY;

    gitprefix(parse_optsST)(&o, argc, argv);

    /**
     * Try to open the repository at the given path (or at the current
     * directory if none was given).
     */
    gitret(check_lg2(git_repository_open_ext(&repo, o.repodir, 0, NULL),
          "Could not open repository", o.repodir));

    if (git_repository_is_bare(repo))
        gitret(fatal("Cannot report status on bare repository",
            git_repository_path(repo)));

show_status:
    if (o.repeat)
        printf("\033[H\033[2J");

    /**
     * Run status on the repository
     *
     * We use `git_status_list_new()` to generate a list of status
     * information which lets us iterate over it at our
     * convenience and extract the data we want to show out of
     * each entry.
     *
     * You can use `git_status_foreach()` or
     * `git_status_foreach_ext()` if you'd prefer to execute a
     * callback for each entry. The latter gives you more control
     * about what results are presented.
     */

    if (o.showsubmod) {
        int submod_count = 0;
        gitret(check_lg2(git_submodule_foreach(repo, gitprefix(print_submodST), &submod_count),
            "Cannot iterate submodules", o.repodir));
    }

    if (o.format == FORMAT_LONG)
        gitprefix(ensure_there_are_changes_to_stash)(repo);
    else {
        gitret(check_lg2(git_status_list_new(&status, repo, &o.statusopt),
        "Could not get status", NULL));
        gitprefix(print_shortST)(repo, status);
        if (status) git_status_list_free(status);
    }


    if (o.repeat) {
        sleep(o.repeat);
        goto show_status;
    }
    if (repo) git_repository_free(repo);
    git_libgit2_shutdown();
    return 0;
}

/**
 * If the user asked for the branch, let's show the short name of the
 * branch.
 */
void gitprefix(show_branchST)(git_repository *repo, int format)
{
    int error = 0;
    const char *branch = NULL;
    git_reference *head = NULL;

    error = git_repository_head(&head, repo);

    if (error == GIT_EUNBORNBRANCH || error == GIT_ENOTFOUND)
        branch = NULL;
    else if (!error) {
        branch = git_reference_shorthand(head);
        git_reference_free(head);
    } else
        gitret(check_lg2(error, "failed to get current branch", NULL));

    if (format == FORMAT_LONG)
        printf("# On branch %s\n",
            branch ? branch : "Not currently on any branch.");
    else
        printf("## %s\n", branch ? branch : "HEAD (no branch)");
}

/**
* This function print out an output similar to git's status command
* in long form, including the command-line hints.
*/

struct collectlist {
    const char * path;
    git_status_t status;
    void * payload;
} *status_list;

int status_list_index = 0;

static int gitprefix(collect_cb)(const char *path, git_status_t status, void *payload)
{
    struct list * p = realloc(status_list, sizeof(*status_list)*(status_list_index+1));
    if (p == NULL) {
        puts("failed to reallocate list");
        return 1;
    }
    status_list = p;
    status_list[status_list_index].path = path;
    status_list[status_list_index].status = status;
    status_list[status_list_index].payload = payload;
    status_list_index++;
    return 0;
}

int nothing(void) {
    int changes_in_index = 0, changed_in_workdir = 0, has_untracked_files = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < status_list_index; i++) {
        char * istatus = NULL;
        if (status_list[i].status == GIT_STATUS_CURRENT)
            continue;
        if (status_list[i].status & GIT_STATUS_INDEX_NEW)
            istatus = "new file: ";
        if (status_list[i].status & GIT_STATUS_INDEX_MODIFIED)
            istatus = "modified: ";
        if (status_list[i].status & GIT_STATUS_INDEX_DELETED)
            istatus = "deleted:  ";
        if (status_list[i].status & GIT_STATUS_INDEX_RENAMED)
            istatus = "renamed:  ";
        if (status_list[i].status & GIT_STATUS_INDEX_TYPECHANGE)
            istatus = "typechange:";
        if (istatus == NULL)
            continue;
        changes_in_index = 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < status_list_index; i++) {
        char *wstatus = NULL;
        if (status_list[i].status & GIT_STATUS_WT_MODIFIED)
            wstatus = "modified: ";
        if (status_list[i].status & GIT_STATUS_WT_DELETED)
            wstatus = "deleted:  ";
        if (status_list[i].status & GIT_STATUS_WT_RENAMED)
            wstatus = "renamed:  ";
        if (status_list[i].status & GIT_STATUS_WT_TYPECHANGE)
            wstatus = "typechange:";
        if (wstatus == NULL)
            continue;
        changed_in_workdir = 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < status_list_index; i++) if (status_list[i].status == GIT_STATUS_WT_NEW) has_untracked_files = 1;

    if (!changes_in_index && !changed_in_workdir && !has_untracked_files) return -1;
    return 0;
}


int gitprefix(ensure_there_are_changes_to_stash)(git_repository *repo)
{
    int error;
    git_status_options opts = GIT_STATUS_OPTIONS_INIT;

    opts.show  = GIT_STATUS_SHOW_INDEX_AND_WORKDIR;
    //opts.flags = GIT_STATUS_OPT_EXCLUDE_SUBMODULES | GIT_STATUS_OPT_INCLUDE_UNTRACKED | GIT_STATUS_OPT_RECURSE_UNTRACKED_DIRS | GIT_STATUS_OPT_INCLUDE_IGNORED | GIT_STATUS_OPT_RECURSE_IGNORED_DIRS;
    opts.flags = GIT_STATUS_OPT_EXCLUDE_SUBMODULES | GIT_STATUS_OPT_INCLUDE_UNTRACKED | GIT_STATUS_OPT_RECURSE_UNTRACKED_DIRS | GIT_STATUS_OPT_INCLUDE_IGNORED | GIT_STATUS_OPT_RECURSE_IGNORED_DIRS | GIT_STATUS_OPT_INCLUDE_UNREADABLE | GIT_STATUS_OPT_RENAMES_FROM_REWRITES | GIT_STATUS_OPT_RENAMES_HEAD_TO_INDEX | GIT_STATUS_OPT_RENAMES_INDEX_TO_WORKDIR;

    status_list_index = 0;
    /*
    pi(GIT_STATUS_CURRENT)
    pi(GIT_STATUS_INDEX_NEW)
    pi(GIT_STATUS_INDEX_MODIFIED)
    pi(GIT_STATUS_INDEX_DELETED)
    pi(GIT_STATUS_INDEX_TYPECHANGE)
    pi(GIT_STATUS_INDEX_RENAMED)
    pi(GIT_STATUS_WT_NEW)
    pi(GIT_STATUS_WT_MODIFIED)
    pi(GIT_STATUS_WT_DELETED)
    pi(GIT_STATUS_WT_TYPECHANGE)
    pi(GIT_STATUS_WT_RENAMED)
    pi(GIT_STATUS_WT_UNREADABLE)
    pi(GIT_STATUS_IGNORED)
    pi(GIT_STATUS_CONFLICTED)
    */

    error = git_status_foreach_ext(repo, &opts, gitprefix(collect_cb), NULL);
    if (error)
    {
        puts("an error has occured collecting status information");
        if (status_list) free(status_list);
        status_list = NULL;
        status_list_index = 0;
        return error;
    }
    if (nothing()) {
        puts("nothing to commit");
        status_list_index = 0;
        if (status_list) free(status_list);
        status_list = NULL;
        return 0;
    }


    gitprefix(show_branchST)(repo, FORMAT_DEFAULT);


    // info collected, print it
    int header = 0, changes_in_index = 0, changed_in_workdir = 0, rm_in_workdir = 0;
    const char *old_path, *new_path;

    for (int i = 0; i < status_list_index; i++) {
        char * istatus = NULL;
        if (status_list[i].status == GIT_STATUS_CURRENT)
            continue;
        if (status_list[i].status & GIT_STATUS_WT_DELETED)
            rm_in_workdir = 1;
        if (status_list[i].status & GIT_STATUS_INDEX_NEW)
            istatus = "new file: ";
        if (status_list[i].status & GIT_STATUS_INDEX_MODIFIED)
            istatus = "modified: ";
        if (status_list[i].status & GIT_STATUS_INDEX_DELETED)
            istatus = "deleted:  ";
        if (status_list[i].status & GIT_STATUS_INDEX_RENAMED)
            istatus = "renamed:  ";
        if (status_list[i].status & GIT_STATUS_INDEX_TYPECHANGE)
            istatus = "typechange:";
        if (istatus == NULL)
            continue;
        if (!header) {
            printf("# Changes to be committed:\n");
            printf("#   (use \"git reset HEAD <file>...\" to unstage)\n");
            printf("#\n");
            header = 1;
        }
        printf("#\t%s  %s\n", istatus, status_list[i].path);
    }

    if (header) {
        changes_in_index = 1;
        printf("#\n");
    }
    header = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < status_list_index; i++) {
        char *wstatus = NULL;
        if (status_list[i].status & GIT_STATUS_WT_MODIFIED)
            wstatus = "modified: ";
        if (status_list[i].status & GIT_STATUS_WT_DELETED)
            wstatus = "deleted:  ";
        if (status_list[i].status & GIT_STATUS_WT_RENAMED)
            wstatus = "renamed:  ";
        if (status_list[i].status & GIT_STATUS_WT_TYPECHANGE)
            wstatus = "typechange:";

        if (wstatus == NULL)
            continue;

        if (!header) {
            printf("# Changes not staged for commit:\n");
            printf("#   (use \"git add%s <file>...\" to update what will be committed)\n", rm_in_workdir ? "/rm" : "");
            printf("#   (use \"git checkout -- <file>...\" to discard changes in working directory)\n");
            printf("#\n");
            header = 1;
        }
        printf("#\t%s  %s\n", wstatus, status_list[i].path);
    }
    if (header) {
        changed_in_workdir = 1;
        printf("#\n");
    }
    header = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < status_list_index; i++) {
        if (status_list[i].status == GIT_STATUS_WT_NEW) {
            if (!header) {
                printf("# Untracked files:\n");
                printf("#   (use \"git add <file>...\" to include in what will be committed)\n");
                printf("#\n");
                header = 1;
            }
            printf("#\t%s\n", status_list[i].path);
        }
    }
    header = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < status_list_index; i++) {
        if (status_list[i].status == GIT_STATUS_IGNORED) {
            if (!header) {
                printf("# Ignored files:\n");
                printf("#   (use \"git add -f <file>...\" to include in what will be committed)\n");
                printf("#\n");
                header = 1;
            }
            printf("#\t%s\n", status_list[i].path);
        }
    }
    if (!changes_in_index && changed_in_workdir) printf("no changes added to commit (use \"git add\" and/or \"git commit -a\")\n");

    if (status_list) free(status_list);
    status_list = NULL;
    status_list_index = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

then it works with

```
0> status
## master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   renamed:    b/j
#   renamed:    b/l
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   j/j
#   j/l
#   test_Copy.
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
0>
```

however i cannot detect renames

and the source code seems to do

https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/c43658f62ee268a0b5ee13f5764544882245063c/src/status.c#L398

```
const git_status_entry *git_status_byindex(git_status_list *status, size_t i)
{
    assert(status);

    return git_vector_get(&status->paired, i);
}
```

>

https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/45dc219f656ff05c06246eec2b36e6805cdf8012/src/vector.h#L60

```
GIT_INLINE(void *) git_vector_get(const git_vector *v, size_t position)
{
    return (position < v->length) ? v->contents[position] : NULL;
}
```

And i cant seem to find the structures specified, specifically git_diff_delta, new_file, and old_file, but i did find this

```
typedef struct {
    git_status_t status;
    git_diff_delta *head_to_index;
    git_diff_delta *index_to_workdir;
} git_status_entry;
```

and from help via C auto completiion (may be incomplete) i managed to build up a full structure of what it should look like:

```
s // git_status_entry *
s->head_to_index // git_diff_delta *
s->head_to_index->flags // uint32_t
s->head_to_index->new_file // git_diff_file
s->head_to_index->new_file.flags // uint32_t
s->head_to_index->new_file.id // git_oid
s->head_to_index->new_file.id_abbrev // uint16_t
s->head_to_index->new_file.mode // uint16_t
s->head_to_index->new_file.path // const char *
s->head_to_index->new_file.size // git_off_t
s->head_to_index->nfiles // uint16_t
s->head_to_index->old_file // git_diff_file
s->head_to_index->old_file.flags // uint32_t
s->head_to_index->old_file.id // git_oid
s->head_to_index->old_file.id_abbrev // uint16_t
s->head_to_index->old_file.mode // uint16_t
s->head_to_index->old_file.path // const char *
s->head_to_index->old_file.size // git_off_t
s->head_to_index->similarity // uint16_t
s->head_to_index->status // git_delta_t
s->index_to_workdir // git_diff_delta *
s->index_to_workdir->flags // uint32_t
s->index_to_workdir->new_file // git_diff_file
s->index_to_workdir->new_file.flags // uint32_t
s->index_to_workdir->new_file.id // git_oid
s->index_to_workdir->new_file.id_abbrev // uint16_t
s->index_to_workdir->new_file.mode // uint16_t
s->index_to_workdir->new_file.path // const char *
s->index_to_workdir->new_file.size // git_off_t
s->index_to_workdir->nfiles // uint16_t
s->index_to_workdir->old_file // git_diff_file
s->index_to_workdir->old_file.flags // uint32_t
s->index_to_workdir->old_file.id // git_oid
s->index_to_workdir->old_file.id_abbrev // uint16_t
s->index_to_workdir->old_file.mode // uint16_t
s->index_to_workdir->old_file.path // const char *
s->index_to_workdir->old_file.size // git_off_t
s->index_to_workdir->similarity // uint16_t
s->index_to_workdir->status // git_delta_t
s->status // git_status_t
```

output:

```
Enter command line arguments.
> status a/0
ret = 0 (none)
ret = 0 (none)
ret = 0 (the global/xdg file 'ignore' doesn't exist: No such file or directory)
s is not NULL
s->status is not NULL
s->head_to_index is not NULL
s->head_to_index->old_file is not NULL
s->head_to_index->old_file.path is NULL
s->head_to_index->old_file.path = (null)
s->head_to_index->new_file is not NULL
s->head_to_index->new_file.path is NULL
s->head_to_index->new_file.path = (null)
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
old_path = (null)
new_path = (null)
#   new file:   (null)
s is not NULL
s->status is not NULL
s->head_to_index is not NULL
s->head_to_index->old_file is not NULL
s->head_to_index->old_file.path is NULL
s->head_to_index->old_file.path = (null)
s->head_to_index->new_file is not NULL
s->head_to_index->new_file.path is NULL
s->head_to_index->new_file.path = (null)
old_path = (null)
new_path = (null)
#   new file:   (null)
s is not NULL
s->status is not NULL
s->head_to_index is not NULL
s->head_to_index->old_file is not NULL
s->head_to_index->old_file.path is NULL
s->head_to_index->old_file.path = (null)
s->head_to_index->new_file is not NULL
s->head_to_index->new_file.path is NULL
s->head_to_index->new_file.path = (null)
old_path = (null)
new_path = (null)
#   new file:   (null)
```

Status.c

```
#include <git2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define ps(x) printf("%s = %s\n", #x, x);

#define gitprefix(x) git_libgit_version_2_api_##x


#define giterr(x) { printf("%s = %d (%s)\n", #x, x, giterr_last()?giterr_last()->message:"none"); }

#define giterror(...) { \
    printf("error: " __VA_ARGS__); \
    printf(" (%s)", giterr_last()?giterr_last()->message:"none"); \
    printf("\n"); \
    return -2; \
}

#define giterrorn(...) { \
    printf("error: " __VA_ARGS__); \
    printf(" (%s)", giterr_last()?giterr_last()->message:"none"); \
    printf("\n"); \
    return NULL; \
}

#define gitret(x) { \
    int ret = x ; \
    if (ret) return ret; \
}

#define gitisnull(x) { \
    if (x == NULL) printf("%s is NULL\n", #x); \
    else printf("%s is not NULL\n", #x); \
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    git_repository *repo = NULL;
    git_status_list *status;
    git_status_options statusopt = { GIT_STATUS_OPTIONS_INIT };

    git_libgit2_init();

    statusopt.show  = GIT_STATUS_SHOW_INDEX_AND_WORKDIR;
    statusopt.flags = GIT_STATUS_OPT_INCLUDE_UNTRACKED |
        GIT_STATUS_OPT_RENAMES_HEAD_TO_INDEX |
        GIT_STATUS_OPT_SORT_CASE_SENSITIVELY;

    /**
     * Try to open the repository at the given path (or at the current
     * directory if none was given).
     */
    int ret = git_repository_open(&repo, argv[1]);
    giterr(ret)
    if (ret < 0) {
        git_libgit2_shutdown();
        giterror("Could not open repository %s", argv[1]);
    }

    ret = git_repository_head_unborn(repo);
    giterr(ret)
    if (ret == 1) {
        git_libgit2_shutdown();
        giterror("Cannot report status on bare repository %s", argv[1]);
    }

    /**
     * Run status on the repository
     *
     * We use `git_status_list_new()` to generate a list of status
     * information which lets us iterate over it at our
     * convenience and extract the data we want to show out of
     * each entry.
     *
     * You can use `git_status_foreach()` or
     * `git_status_foreach_ext()` if you'd prefer to execute a
     * callback for each entry. The latter gives you more control
     * about what results are presented.
     */
    ret = git_status_list_new(&status, repo, &statusopt);
    giterr(ret)
    if (ret < 0) {
        git_libgit2_shutdown();
        giterror("Could not get status of repository %s", argv[1]);
    }

    size_t i, maxi = git_status_list_entrycount(status);
    const git_status_entry *s;
    int header = 0, changes_in_index = 0;
    int changed_in_workdir = 0, rm_in_workdir = 0;
    const char *old_path, *new_path;

    /** Print index changes. */

    for (i = 0; i < maxi; ++i) {
        char *istatus = NULL;

        s = git_status_byindex(status, i);

        gitisnull(s)

        if (s!=NULL) {
            gitisnull(s->status)
            gitisnull(s->head_to_index)
            if (s->head_to_index!=NULL) {
                gitisnull(s->head_to_index->old_file)
                gitisnull(s->head_to_index->old_file.path)
                ps(s->head_to_index->old_file.path)
                gitisnull(s->head_to_index->new_file)
                gitisnull(s->head_to_index->new_file.path)
                ps(s->head_to_index->new_file.path)
            }
        }


        if (s->status == GIT_STATUS_CURRENT)
            continue;

        if (s->status & GIT_STATUS_WT_DELETED)
            rm_in_workdir = 1;

        if (s->status & GIT_STATUS_INDEX_NEW)
            istatus = "new file: ";
        if (s->status & GIT_STATUS_INDEX_MODIFIED)
            istatus = "modified: ";
        if (s->status & GIT_STATUS_INDEX_DELETED)
            istatus = "deleted:  ";
        if (s->status & GIT_STATUS_INDEX_RENAMED)
            istatus = "renamed:  ";
        if (s->status & GIT_STATUS_INDEX_TYPECHANGE)
            istatus = "typechange:";

        if (istatus == NULL)
            continue;

        if (!header) {
            printf("# Changes to be committed:\n");
            printf("#   (use \"git reset HEAD <file>...\" to unstage)\n");
            printf("#\n");
            header = 1;
        }

        old_path = s->head_to_index->old_file.path;
        new_path = s->head_to_index->new_file.path;

        ps(old_path);
        ps(new_path);

        if (old_path && new_path && strcmp(old_path, new_path))
            printf("#\t%s  %s -> %s\n", istatus, old_path, new_path);
        else
            printf("#\t%s  %s\n", istatus, old_path ? old_path : new_path);
    }

    git_status_list_free(status);

    git_repository_free(repo);
    git_libgit2_shutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the type-linking is not great… All public types can be found in the sidebar under Types. So https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/type/git_diff_delta, and https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/type/git_diff_file are the ones you're after.

Comment: There's also a status example [here](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/ex/HEAD/status.html).

It's hard to tell how you're getting those results without your actual repository state, but I tried locally and got this :
    old_path = file3
    new_path = file3

My test repo contains a file1 (committed in the previous commit), file2 (unstaged), and file3 (staged, ie `git add`-ed). So, it seems to work for staged files, and your code is deliberately skipping over the non-staged ones (`GIT_STATUS_WT_*`), since you don't have an `istatus` for those.

Comment: git stat a/0 shows that all the files are in stage 0

Comment: and i just add the files using the add example in examples/add.c

Comment: oddly it works correctly if i use a foreach instead

Comment: however i cannot get the status flags for it nor can i detect renames

Comment: @tiennou if im using git_status_foreach_ext how would i detect a file rename

Comment: There's no guarantee that you have _any_ data in the `head_to_index` section without knowing what the status of that entry is.  What's the `status` of that item?

Comment: @EdwardThomson 1

Comment: @EdwardThomson index_to_workdir is 7, and 4